# C++: When using a value called from a getter method of an object, a random negative int is outputted?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, generics, return

The following is my file TotalTemplate.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class TotalTemplate{
public:
//protected:
    T* items;
    int itemsAdded;
    int amountOfItems;

//public:

    //Exception for trying to add items when its passed its limit
    class TooManyItems{ };

    //Exception for trying to call total before the total has been reached
    class IncompleteTotal{ };

    TotalTemplate(int amountOfItems){
        TotalTemplate::amountOfItems = amountOfItems;
        items = new T[amountOfItems];
        itemsAdded = 0;
    }

    TotalTemplate(int amountOfItems, T firstItem){
        TotalTemplate::amountOfItems = amountOfItems;
        items[] = new T[amountOfItems];
        items[0] = firstItem;
        itemsAdded = 1;
    }

    void addItem(T item){
        if (itemsAdded >= amountOfItems)
            throw TooManyItems();
        else{
            items[itemsAdded-1] = item;
            itemsAdded++;
        }
    }

    //Returns the amount of items added so far
    int getAmountAdded(){
        return itemsAdded;
    }

    T getTotal(){//Here is the method definition that is giving me problems
        if (itemsAdded < amountOfItems)
            throw IncompleteTotal();
        else{
            T total=items[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < itemsAdded; i++)
                total += items[i];
            return total;
        }
    }


};


void main(){
    //using int to fill the generic type T
    cout << "Enter the amount of items to be totaled: ";
    int totalAmountOfItems = getInt();
    TotalTemplate<int> *total=new TotalTemplate<int>(totalAmountOfItems);
    while (true){
        cout << total->getAmountAdded() << " items added so far!\nSelect one of the following actions to take.\n";
        cout << "(1) Add an item.\n";
        cout << "(2) View total.\n";
        cout << "(3) Exit Program.\n";
        switch (menuSelect(3)){
        case 1://Add an item
            try{
                cout << "Enter a number to add: ";
                int item = getInt();
                total->addItem(item);
            }
            catch (TotalTemplate<int>::TooManyItems){
                cout << "\nItems given exceeds expected limit.\n\n";
            }
            break;

        case 2://View Total
            try{
                int totalInt = total->getTotal(); //Here is my problem
                cout << "The total is: " << totalInt << endl<<endl;
            }
            catch (TotalTemplate<int>::IncompleteTotal){
                cout << "\nRunning Total has not yet reached total amount of items yet.\n\n";
            }
            break;

        case 3: //Exit program
            return;
        }
    }
         cout << "\n\nExiting program...";
         _getch();
}
```

The problem I'm getting is in the main method, when I call total.getTotal(), instead of return an expected int, being the total of all the items added together, I get a totally random int outputted: -842150451

My guess is that it's outputting something instead of the value returned from getTotal(), but I'm not sure how or why or how to fix it. I come from a Java background so I feel like I'm out of habit doing improper oop C++ practice.

Also, getInt() and menuSelect() are methods I have reused from previous codes multiple times, so I excluded them from the file for simplicity sake.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As someone coming from Java you should never use `new`. It is just bad style and unnecessarily difficult and error prone. Allocate on the stack instead, for example `TotalTemplate<int> total(totalAmountOfItems);` and use `std::vector<T>` internally.

Comment: This is C++. You need to free up the memory by calling `delete[] items` in the destructor. Otherwise it will cause memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

this line in `addItem`

```
items[itemsAdded-1] = item;
```

should be

```
items[itemsAdded] = item;
```

Comment: Weird, I can't believe it was such a simple thing. I remember thinking I had a really good reason why I had it itemsAdded-1, so I guess I just glanced over it...

Comment: Can you explain what that negative int was, so I can catch it in future reference?

Comment: When you allocate an array of ints (or any primitive) whatever memory is assigned is not cleared. So you were basically looking at uninitialized memory. So whatever was stored at that memory location before is now 'assigned' to the array of ints. To avoid that you can use the `memset` function to **zero** the memory if desired.